# Why does Intellisense see a namespace, but compiler does not?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, sendgrid

The screen shot below shows that VS 2012 intellisense picks up `Helpers` namespace from `SendGrid` namespace, but there is still a compile time error stating

```
The type or namespace name 'Helpers' does not exist in the namespace 'SendGrid'
(are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

[image: SendGrid.Helpers intellisense]

What I checked:

- The project is .NET 4.5 and that never changed.
- `SendGrid` and `SendGrid.CSharp.HTTP.Client` references both have
  v4.0.30319 runtime version, same as the rest of references.
- `Newtonsoft.JSON` used by `SendGrid` is also the same runtime version.
- Both are set to copy local True.
- There are no other errors in the project.
- F12 following a method from `SendGrid.Helpers` namespace navigates to its definition successfully, so I surmise there is no issue with the referenced DLL???
- Cleaned and rebuilt the solution, restarted VS and machine.
- Switched .NET version of the project between 3.5 and 4.5 several times back and forth.

`SendGrid` was added using Nuget to an existing project.

Comment: Clean the solution and try to rebuild it, if you haven't already done that.

Comment: Sometimes these strange things can happen when you have a class with the same name as the namespace. In your example: If you had a class named Helpers in the SendGrid namespace.

Comment: @GregaMohorko Nope. It is perfectly legal to have `Namespace1.Name` and `Namespace2.Name`. Suggesting otherwise is absurd as it would make development summarily impossible. And no, I do not have the same namespace or class for that matter.

Comment: I meant exactly the same. When I was writing the comment, I didn't know that SendGrid is not your library and that you got it from NuGet.

Comment: From all googling I gather that this should be rather .NET version problem, but it escapes me where it is hiding. If I can F12 on the method of that namespace, and it follows to the definition, than there should be no source code issue, correct?

Comment: Are you using PCL?

Comment: This might be because you are targetting an older framework version than the one the Sendgrid component is built for. Edit: Sorry, did not see that you have already tried changing the version.

Comment: @MatthewWhited What is PCL?

Comment: That's probably no... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391(v=vs.110).aspx .. at least not on purpose.  SendGrid's nutget may be PCL.

Comment: Check for an assembly redirect in the app.config/web.config

Comment: If that doesn't work remove the nuget package and re-add it.  If you changed the assembly version after the nuget package was added it can cause all kinds of weird issues.  (Remove, clean, add, clean, build)

Comment: Removing/re-adding did not work. `Newtonsoft.JSON` redirects, but nothing else.

Comment: It isn't very clear why you don't see the warning.  It yells loudly enough: "The primary reference "SendGrid" could not be resolved because it was built against the ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" framework. This is a higher version than the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5".  Changing the project's target is of course the obvious solution, there is no reason left today to limit yourself to 4.5

Comment: Well, other than using an ancient VS version I guess.  Use nuget to retrieve an older version of SendGrid that is still compatible with 4.5 and VS2012.

Comment: @HansPassant Where should I see the warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing an older version `SendGrid-4.0` as per Hans solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of times this is caused by a build break during a design-time build, see https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-project-system/blob/master/docs/design-time-builds.md#diagnosing-design-time-builds for instructions on diagnosing these.